# A question on notation for open sets

Tags: soft-question, notation

Yesterday I was presenting a seminar where I started using this notation to make sentences shorter; whenever I wanted to say that $A$ was open in $B$, I would write $A\underset{op}\subset B$, with the same being valid for closed, $A\underset{cl}\subset B$.

Is there any problem in writing it this way? Has someone used something like this before?

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) might also interest you.

Comment: Won't it be hard to see in a chalk and board lesson? :P

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking in LaTeX. But I guess your notation is easy to understand, even though I would probably define it the first time. So something like " Let $A$ be an open subset in $B$ (in the following $A\subset_{op} B$)... "

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in something easier to write down in boards for students, instead of writing erery time "A open in B", "C open in D". But yes, some previous definition must be in order to avoid misunderstandings.

I guess I could use this in LaTeX formatting but I'm afraid it could look unorthodox and be depreciated... Maybe I could do this in papers after PhD :D

Comment: @KubaHelsztyński, what is that used for?

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment. It was: Be sure the latter will not be take for $A\Subset B$, which is commonly used as either '$A$ is compactly contained in $B$' (i.e. closure of $A$ is a compact subset of $B$) or '$B$ contains $A$ together with its closure.'.

Comment: Thanks @KubaHelsztyński. I have never seen this notation before, but thanks for the warning. Anyway, the mistake can be avoided writing $A\underset{closed}\subset B$, I guess.

Comment: +1 @macydanim For those too lazy to visit the link, apparently there _are_ Unicode characters defined to mean open and closed subsets respectively. See [⟃](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27c3/index.htm) and [⫏](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2acf/index.htm). Though as usual, I wish there's an easy way to find out where the Unicode people got those symbols from. (I have not encountered them myself in my education, and would love to know who introduced these notations.)

Comment: @WillieWong That is also something that bothered me. Especially for the link I gave, I didn't know whether the notation was simply made up, but it appears that it is somehow known (even though I never saw that notation before).

Comment: @macydanim of the symbols in the [Unicode math operators block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode), there are certainly more that I have never seen before than that I recognize. I've always just assumed that someone somewhere knew what he was doing. I mean, it is similar to the CJK block for East Asian languages: I'd wager there's no one person who actually knows the proper pronunciation of _all_ of the Chinese characters included in Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your formulation on a blackboard it should be fine as long as you define it the first time you use it. For LaTeX you could also create a shortcut for the term "open subset" if you want to make sure you stick to the correct formulation and still want to avoid typing it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

One of my professors used the notations
$$A\subset\!\!{\scriptstyle{\circ}}\, B, \quad\quad A\subset\!{\scriptscriptstyle{\Box}}\, B$$
for open and closed subsets, respectively. I like it much..